# Windows server monitoring

Tags: windows, monitoring

I have RDP access to the windows server. I used to do manually check the disk space and RAM usage on all my windows server. I can't install or enable any service on the remote servers. Is there any way, to automate the task to check the disk space and RAM/CPU usage on remote windows server with RDP access only.

Answer (score 1):

No, not with RDP - as its name entails, the Remote Desktop Protocol is an interactive system for users to access their desktop - hardly an automation system.

But you don't need to install anything, Windows comes with full remote management possibilities out of the box. For example, Inside a PowerShell session (on *your* PC) just use:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName SERVER1,SERVER2,SERVER3 | select DeviceID,VolumeName,Size,FreeSpace
```

You can add as many servers as you want to the list. If your local login account does not have permissions to access the remote servers, simply add the `-Credential DOMAIN\LOGIN` parameter to the command above.

Finally, if you encounter a login error even with an account that is an administrator of the remote servers, you must check that firewall rules do not prevent remote administration from working on the server side. You may want to use (inside an RDP session) the PowerShell command `Enable-PSRemoting`.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to check servers. But I recommanded to install tools (open source) like nagios or zabbix.
Nagios is a good open source for monitoring with web access and email alerting. You need to install **NSclient** on the windows server which allows nagios the access to resources.
About the email alerting, you need to install an smtp server, that will send mail each time there's a critical situation. (postfix or sendmail)
this is a tutorial link to install nagios: 
http://itgration.blogspot.com/2014/09/installation-nagios-306.html